# Function that opens a web page and returns a dictionary of all the links and their text

Tags: python

Write a function that opens a web page and returns a dictionary of all thelinks and their text on that page.  A link is defined by an HTML tag that looks like

< ahref="http://my.computer.com/some/file.html">link  text < /a>

The link is everything in quotes after thehref=, and the text is everything between the > and the . For the example above, the entry in a dictionary would look like:

"{"http:// my.computer.com/some/file.html" : " link text ", ...}"

Here's my code so far I've been stuck on for a few hours. How do I accomplish this problem?

```
import urllib.request


def Urls(webpage):
    url = webpage
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    url_list = {}
    for line in page:
        if '<a href=' in line:
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answers suggesting to tackle this problem with regular expressions *might* work, they'll fail (unless you take measures) when e.g. the link is split over several lines. E.g. this is perfectly valid HTML:

```
<a
href="../path">link</a>
```

There are some other edge cases to consider. In general, HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions and there's some [excellent prose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2476444) written about that. By the way, the construction `"a href" in line` is a less powerful form of regular expression, that just searches in a line and has the same drawbacks.

Instead, you should be looking into libraries that parse HTML as a properly formatted XML-document. In Python, the go-to library would be [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). With it, you can quickly get all links in a webpage, e.g. like this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.imdb.com/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('a') # returns all links as a list
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)] # some anchors might have no href attribute, by specifying href=True, you'll get only those that do
```

The [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is very well-documented, with tons of examples. Well worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Urls(webpage):
    url = webpage
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    url_list = {}
    for line in page:
        if '<a href=' in line:
            try:
                url = line.split('<a href="')[-1].split('">')[0]
                txt = line.split('<a href="')[-1].split('">')[-1].split('< /a>')[0]
                url_list[url] = txt
             except:
                 pass
     return url_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r=re.compile("<\s*a\s*href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\s*/a\s*>")
list = r.findall(line)
for tuple in list:
    url_list[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```

Comment: Please don't recommend regular expressions to parse HTML. There are stable libraries for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Using `requests` and `SoupStrainer` for simplicity/efficiency:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

def get_urls(webpage):
    res = requests.get(webpage)
    links = [l for l in BeautifulSoup(res.text, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))             
             if l.has_attr('href')]
    return links
```